# slideshow with jquery fancybox and iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to see if it is possible to create slideshow of html pages similar to flipboard.com
landing page.

I am able to load the html page using iframe in fancybox.

The page is at: http://yshara.com/test.html

My html/javascript looks like:

```
<body onload="$('.extLink').trigger('click');"> 
  <div class="container">   
    <div id="nextslide">
  <a class="extLink" href="http://google.com">Search the world with different sites.</a>    
      <a class="extLink"  href="http://yahoo.com">Next</a>
      <a class="extLink" href="http://Bing.com">Next</a>        
</div>      
  </div>
</body>
```

I was wondering if any of you javascript experts can help me with this one.

1. The first page is google.com, but it skips it to the next one, yahoo.com
2. How do I cycle back to the first page?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be triggering the .extLink class, as it's triggering 3 times. Try `$('.extLink:eq(0)').click()`

Comment: Thanks thugsb, that helped. Do you have any idea how to cycle the links?

Comment: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ is the best cycler on the web, although I'm not sure how it will play with fancybox. In fact, I'm not really sure why you're using the fancybox at all - it doesn't seem to be what you want. I'd recommend using jQuery.cycle exclusively. You can control the cycle effects very precisely (see advanced examples), and with this cycle plugin, you can do some really cool stuff: http://jayis.net/thomas/cycle/